# Triggering workflow automatically by a particular date

Tags: sharepoint, date, workflow, designer

I am new to Sharepoint. I have a list where the date is given in a column and on that particular date the workflow must automatically trigger.

```
I went to sharepoint designer but couldn't set the value to date.
```

How do I trigger a workflow automatically by a particular date??

Please help. I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!!
Sharmi

Answer (score 2):

My best bet would be to just start the workflow when the item is added / edited and then add a waitactivity that waits for the period of time from now till the set date.